# FeinCMS search rich text content data

Tags: sphinx, django-haystack, whoosh, feincms

I am working on an existing Django project that uses FeinCMS for the content management.

I am trying to implement a 'Site Search'.

Using Haystack and Whoosh I can happily search the standard Django models.

However, when I try to use the same Haystack recommended approach to the FeincCMS 'Page' rich-text-content model, I'm not having much luck.

I'm wondering if this can indeed be done and if anyone has successfully used the Haystack/FeinCMS combo before?

Or do I need to look at a different approach. Someone has mentioned Sphinx to me?

Comment: Update: unfortunately I did not manage to get this working and due to time constraints ended up trying a 3rd party plug-in site search (swiftype.com). We'll see how we go with that. 

Another possible alternative which I might investigate next time is to install www.opensearchserver.com which looks like it could cover most things.